# Lazyloading Images Breaks loadHTMLString

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, image, wordpress

I am pulling JSON data from a blog, and then using the url of a post to load the post content, and content alone.

As of right now it loads the post content fine, but won't load the images. I think it's because the blog has a lazyloading plugin. I need the plugin for the website, but is there a way I can still load the images without having to load the entire webpage?

```
<img src="http://www.blog.com/wp-content/plugins/lazy-load/images/1x1.trans.gif" data-lazy-src="actual_imageurl" width="320" height="480" />

<noscript><img src="actual_imageurl" width="320" height="480" /></noscript>
```

An alternate way to fix it would be to force the webView to load the `<noscript>` but I can't figure that out either.

Comment: When I copied your image URL and tried to open it in browser I saw 404 error, may be problem in it?

Comment: @zakhej, Nah, the actual url is http://wheninmanila.com/wp-content/plugins/lazy-load/images/1x1.trans.gif and http://www.wheninmanila.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Top-10-Blogger-Etiquette-Tips-How-to-be-a-Classy-Blogger_thumb.jpg